# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.NetInfo.isConnected')

Tags: react-native, android-studio, androidx

I have a trouble with launching my app.. Tried everything that I found in similar topics, but still no success :(

I use:

Android Studio 3.5.3

Gradle Version 6

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.5

I successfully migrated to Androidx using jetifier (I hope so)

@react-native-community/netinfo version is 5.5.0

build.grandle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist") }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo" }
        mavenCentral()
                 }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
                 }
            }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url ("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android") }
        maven { url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist") }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
        jcenter()
                 }
             }

ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 28
    targetSdkVersion    = 28
    minSdkVersion = 16
    buildToolsVersion   = "29.0.3"
    //androidXCore = "1.0.2"
    supportLibVersion="28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
                        !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.0"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "28.+"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                    details.useVersion "12.+"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                    details.useVersion "+"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'modelalliance_client'
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-share'
project(':react-native-share').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-share/android')
include ':react-native-fetch-blob'
project(':react-native-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
include ':rn-fetch-blob'
project(':rn-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-touch-id'
project(':react-native-touch-id').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-touch-id/android')
include ':react-native-pdf'
project(':react-native-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-pdf/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':react-native-document-picker'
project(':react-native-document-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-image-resizer'
project(':react-native-image-resizer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':@react-native-community-netinfo'
project(':@react-native-community-netinfo').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android')

include ':app'
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

def useIntlJsc = false

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/merged_assets/release/out",
    enableHermes: true,
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
    bundleInStaging: true,       // Add this
    bundleInInternalTest: true,  // Add this
    bundleInRelease: true
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false)

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.modelalliance_client"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
          //  abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    project.ext.sentryCli = [
            logLevel: "debug",
            flavorAware: false,
            //add
            enableHermes: false
    ]

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable true
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a","x86","x86_64"
            exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        }

    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug{ minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release }
        all {minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release}

    }




    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3,"x86_64":4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    if (useIntlJsc) {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
    } else {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-share')
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-touch-id')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-document-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community-netinfo')

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc:r241213"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0"


    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5"  // From node_modules

    implementation(project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1') {
            force = true
        }
    }
     implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0')
     compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
         exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
         exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
     }
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
     implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
     implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1"
     implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
     implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.1.0-alpha03'
     compile('com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0') { force = true }

     implementation 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2.1'

    implementation(project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1') {
           force = true
        }
    }
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

    if (enableHermes) {

        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/"
         debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
     } else {
          implementation jscFlavor
     }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=divo.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=Glaz5756523
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=Glaz5756523
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.jetifier.blacklist = your-troublemaker-library.jar
```

Comment: Hello there! Can you please share your error messages?